# На вход программы подается число k.Найдите все пифагоровы тройки, такие, что c < k и выведите их количество для заданного k

Tags: python

Есть задача

На вход программы подается число k. Найдите все пифагоровы тройки, такие, что c <k и выведите их количество для заданного k.

Например, если k = 10, то условию удовлетворяет только одна тройка

и программа должна вывести 1.

Sample Input:

10
Sample Output:

1

```
k = int(input())
count = 0
numbers = []
for c in range(3, k):
    for a in range(2, c):
        for b in range(1, a):
            if a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2 and not c in numbers:
                count += 1
                numbers.append(c)
print(count)
```

Не могу понять где ошибаюсь в написание кода.Подскажите плиз:)

Comment: откуда вообще известно, что есть ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Дело в том что в среде разработки код работает,а вот в учебной программе выдаёт ошибку.Если вас не затруднит не могли бы вы написать код для этой задачи с комментариями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибаетесь вот где - нельзя просто проверять наличие `с` во множестве, так как одно `с` может участвовать в разных тройках - например `7,24,25` и `15,20,25`.

Поэтому храните всю тройку как кортеж, или достаточно хранить любую пару из тройки - например, a и b